# Sql , Get similar rows with product id into column in single row dynamically on column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having tables like this:

## products

```
product_id, product_primary_image,product_name
```

## product_image

```
image_id,product_id,image_url
```

## Desired result:

```
product_id    product_primary_image    product_name  image_url1   image_url2   image_url3
```

This is what i have tried so far to get the result but

```
  SELECT `product`.`product_id`,`product`.`product_name`,`product`.`product_primary_image`,`product_image`.`image_url` FROM `product_image` LEFT JOIN `product` ON `product`.`product_id` = `product_image`.`product_id`;
```

But its giving out put as

```
product_id   product_name   product_primary_image   image_url

99           301R           Maroon1.jpg             Maroon3.jpg

99           301R           Maroon1.jpg             Maroon2.jpg

99           301R           Maroon1.jpg             Maroon.jpg
```

I want the result as

```
product_id  product_name    product_primary_image   image_url1      image_url2      image_url3

99          301R            Maroon1.jpg             Maroon3.jpg     Maroon2.jpg     Maroon.jpg
```

Comment: The use of backticks strongly suggests MySQL, so I'm removing the other database tags.

Comment: Is there a fixed maximum number of images for each product?  I.E.  how many columns will be needed in the result table?

Comment: @LeeG Maximum of 7 images column, but can we do it for dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get what you want is to put the images into a single column with a delimiter:

```
SELECT p.`product_id`, p.`product_name`, p.`product_primary_image`,
       gruop_concat(pi.`image_url`) as urls
FROM `product_image` pi LEFT JOIN
     `product` p
     ON p.`product_id` = pi.`product_id`;
```

EDIT:

You can get three columns, if you like, by using `substring_index()`:

```
SELECT p.`product_id`, p.`product_name`, p.`product_primary_image`,
       min(pi.image_url) as url1,
       substring_index(substring_index(gruop_concat(pi.`image_url`), ',', 2), ',', -1) as url2,
       max(pi.image_Url) as url3
FROM `product_image` pi LEFT JOIN
     `product` p
     ON p.`product_id` = pi.`product_id`;
```

Comment: As I have already described the result that is needed for the case above

Comment: can we do it for my case that i have described above?